# ¿A que se refiere error io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno dentro de flask?

Tags: python, flask

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y me tope con este error a la hora de utilizar Flask.
Copié y pegué el codigo que se encuentra en la pagina oficial de Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
app.run()
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo, Python responde con este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Equipo\Desktop\ING. DE SISTEMAS\Introduccion a la 
programacion\Flask Tutorial\hola_mundo.py", line 8, in <module>
app.run()
File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
click.echo(message)
File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\click\utils.py", line 217, in echo
file = _default_text_stdout()
File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\click\_compat.py", line 621, in func
rv = wrapper_func()
File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\click\_compat.py", line 385, in get_text_stdout
rv = _get_windows_console_stream(sys.stdout, encoding, errors)
File "C:\Users\Equipo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 261, in _get_windows_console_stream
func = _stream_factories.get(f.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

La verdad no se por que se da este error, ya que Flask ha sido instalado correctamente. Repito, soy nuevo y hasta ahora no he encontrado una respuesta clara.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo ejecutas?

Comment: Después de editar en IDLE, undo f5 para ejecutar el programa. Eso si, había olvidado decir que dentro del código hay un app.run()

Comment: Hola Santiago, bienvenido a [es.so]. Colocar la traza completa del error puede ser de ayuda. Prueba a ejecutar el script desde la propia terminal/cmd en vez de hacerlo desde el IDLE.  ¿Que versión de Python, sistema operativo y Flask usas?

Comment: [Parece ser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080829/python-error-io-unsupportedoperation-fileno) que IDLE redefine ciertos objetos de entrada/salida (los sockets entre ellos) y les elimina el método `fileno()`. En definitiva, no se puede ejecutar ese programa desde el IDLE. Haciéndolo desde línea de comandos no deberías tener problema.

Comment: Es una posibilidad a descartar,  pero yo al menos no puedo reproducirlo ni en Python 3.6 ni en 2.7 actualizados ejecutando en el IDLE, ni en Windows ni en Linux tengo problema alguno.

Comment: Hola de nuevo! Utilizo Windows 10 y mi version de Flask es la 1.0.2, que es la  más nueva en mi entendimiento.

Comment: Intente correr el codigo en el cmd y me resultó en la creación del server  http://127.0.0.1:5000 donde efectivamente se imprimió el mensaje 'Hola Mundo!'.

Comment: Sin embargo aun me queda la duda de porque se da el error, ya que en los tutoriales y guias que he visto no aparece ningún error, por lo que temo que el paquete este mal instalado o haya algún otro problema  que pueda generarme inconvenientes a larga si quiero seguir usando Flask. Agregue el error completo por si eso puede ayudar a localizar el problema.

Comment: De igual manera agradezco infinitamente la ayuda que me han proporcionado.

Comment: @SantiagoCollantesZuluaga Como ya indiqué en un comentario anterior, parece que ese bug ocurre al ejecutar desde el IDLE ciertos programas que usan sockets (como es el caso). Según el comentario de FJSevilla, parece que hay versiones del IDLE en que el problema no aparece. Pero si te funciona desde línea de comandos (que es la forma más habitual de lanzarlo), yo no me preocuparía ni le daría más vueltas.

Comment: Santiago he podido reproducirlo en Windows con Python 3.6 actualizando `click`, no así en Linux. Efectivamente el problema está en el IDLE, ejecutando el script desde la terminal no hay problema.

Comment: Mirando el _stack trace_ del error, parece que se produce, no en relación con los sockets como yo pensaba, sino a causa de la biblioteca `click` (que Flask usa para facilitar la creación de interfaces de comando). Aparentemente esa biblioteca intenta obtener un _handle_ de la consola de windows, y fracasa. Lo que no es de extrañar porque cuando lo ejecutas desde IDLE no hay consola de windows.

Comment: Ya llevo un rato trabajando y hasta ahora no se ha presentado ningún  otro error. Te agradezco muchísimo por todo el apoyo. @abulafia

Comment: A ti también @FJSevilla

Answer (score 0):

No estas agregando la linea de ejecución correctamente, debería ir así:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Si te das cuenta, estoy agregando la linea if **name** == '**main**':